# Change background color of textview when on clicked on this

Tags: android, textview, sharedpreferences, background-color

I has a textview, I want set this background color when textview on clicked and reset default background color when textview on clicked again. And save this background color to Sharedpreference.
How can do it? sorry my english is bad.

Comment: togglebutton is designed for this purpose. it is free and feel free to use it :)) you can also use custom xml drawable.

Comment: thanks but I must use Textview not Togglebutton, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do Something like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String restoredText = prefs.getString("color", "default");

TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String restoredText = prefs.getString("color", "default");
        if (restoredText.equals("default")) {
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("my_preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("color", "gray");
            editor.commit();
        } else {
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cccccc"));
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("my_preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("color", "default");
            editor.commit();

        }


    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but we dont need use *final*?

Comment: Yes. dont need to use final

Comment: So we need update UI on thread? ex: runOnUIThread or Handler?

Comment: It has  a bug, when this this activity loading color will change?